# How to extract every row where the Col2 matches any Col1 in R

Tags: r, dataset, character, extract, matching

I have a large dataset, 4,000 observations, and two vars. The two vars are characters, names specifically. I want to remove any rows where the col2 (Last Name) does not equal exactly the character of ANY col 1(First Name).

[Here is a look at what the dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWnDp.png)

I've tried using %in% but it returns the rows that have repeats on 1 column not across columns.

I've seen a lot of advice on how to match one or two or several specific character strings to another column and then extract. However, in this case I don't know exactly which those specific strings are that I want to match. I am hoping to find a way for R to locate those cross column matches for me.

Here is an example input df:

```
First  Last 

Joe    Weinberg
Hilton Alexander
Tom    Marshall
Fred   Hilton
```

I would want the output df to look like this:

```
First  Last

Hilton Alexander
Fred   Hilton
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, let me know if this helps although i'm still learning the proper formatting for this.     If a list of names (ordered First Name, Last Name|First, Last|etc) looked like this:            Hilton, Alexander| Devin, Booker| Ty, Davis| Booker, Booker| Andre Washington| Fred, Hilton.... I would want the output to only show those rows which share a common first and last name...ex) Hilton, Alexander| Devin, Booker|Booker, Booker| Fred, Hilton. Does this help at all?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same which will avoid long explanation in comments like these. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I want to keep names from the second column that appear in the first collumn. When a name appears in both columns, any row reflecting this "match" should be retained.

Comment: Match: When a Last Name in one row == First Name from another row. The two "matching" rows would be kept in the df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` like :

```
subset(df, First %in% Last | Last %in% First)

#   First      Last
#2 Hilton Alexander
#4   Fred    Hilton
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like this?

```
library(dplyr)

names_to_drop <- df$First.Name

df <- df %>%
   filter(!(Last.Name %in% names_to_drop))
```

Comment: I tried this but all that happens is the removal of one half of the matched pair.  For example, Fred Hilton remains in the dataset but Hilton Armstrong was removed. My hope is that they both would remain in the dataset. Thanks for bearing with me, I am relatively new to R.

Comment: The code above should have removed Fred Hilton & kept Hilton Armstrong. Are you sure you copied it correctly? Also, I'm now confused about what you want, do you want to: A) remove all Hiltons, b) remove Fred Hilton but keep Hilton Armstrong, C) remove Hilton Armstrong and keep Fred Hilton, D) do something else?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain properly at first. Option D) Do something else. I want the code to keep rows where a first name matches to a last name. Thus, Hilton Armstrong and Fred Armstrong would stay. So anytime a First Name matches a last name, the corresponding rows are kept in the df.

Comment: So you want to keep all names where at least one of the names appears in either `First.Name` or `Last.Name`? If so, you can do it like this: `names_to_keep <- unique(c(df$First.Name, df$Last.Name)) ; df %>% filter(First.Name %in% names_to_keep | Last.Name %in% names_to_keep)`

Comment: Yes, I want to keep all names where at least one of the names appears in either column. However, it seems what you have kindly provided still does work. For example, Hilton Armstrong is still removed but Fred Hilton remains.